# Is it safe to make RefCell Sync+Send if the data it contains is protected by RwLock?

Tags: multithreading, rust, refcell, rwlock

I'm trying to make a thread-safe data type, with locking full encapsulated so that callers never see or directly hold a lock.  (This part works fine.)

Further, there is a requirement that the struct which generates an instance of this data type hold a mutable reference and gives out a mutable reference to the caller. (This is what I'm having trouble with.)

Here is example code that pretty well distills down the problem:

```rust
use std::sync::{Arc, RwLock};
use std::cell::RefCell;

trait ChangeName {
    fn change_name(&mut self, name: String);
}

// MyDataPrivate contains the data I care about.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyDataPrivate {
    name: String,
}
impl ChangeName for MyDataPrivate {
    fn change_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.name = name;
    }
}

// MyData encapsulates locking around MyData.
// Callers never hold a lock directly.
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyData {
    inner: RwLock<MyDataPrivate>,
}
impl ChangeName for MyData {
    fn change_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.inner.write().unwrap().change_name(name);
    }
}

impl MyData {
    fn new(name: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            inner: RwLock::new(MyDataPrivate{name})
        }
    }
}

// MyDataRef provides mutable references to MyData.
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct MyDataRef(Arc<RefCell<MyData>>);
impl ChangeName for MyDataRef {
    fn change_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.0.borrow_mut().change_name(name);
    }
}

// This makes it build.  Is it Safe/Ok since MyData is Send + Sync?
unsafe impl Sync for MyDataRef {}
unsafe impl Send for MyDataRef {}


fn do_stuff<T: Sync + Send>(_t: T) {}


fn main() {
    let mydata = MyData::new("Donner".to_string());
    let mut mydata_ref = MyDataRef(Arc::new(RefCell::new(mydata)));
    
    do_stuff(mydata_ref.clone());
    
    mydata_ref.change_name("Rudolf".to_string());
    
    println!("name: {:?}", mydata_ref);
}
```

See [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=54d5f5f9d0464b1d6c88b3f6bb47c0c8).

The above code will not compile without using `unsafe` to `impl Send + Sync for MyDataRef`.  This is because `RefCell` is not thread-safe.

However, the data I put inside the `RefCell` *is* thread-safe (protected by `RwLock`). So my belief is that makes this particular `RefCell` thread-safe also.

I realize I could use `Arc<RwLock<MyData>>` in `MyDataRef` instead of `Arc<RefCell<MyData>>` but then I  have two `RwLock`s around `MyDataPrivate` which seems unnecessary and gross.

My question is two parts:

1. Is it safe/correct to `impl Send + Sync` for `RefCell` in this situation where the data it contains is 100% `RwLock` protected?

<strike>2) Is there a better way to do this, that still keeps the locking encapsulated away from callers?</strike>
edit: I figured out [a nice solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3dcfbd40781d0f6b60c238fe382f7aba).

ps: in the original code `MyDataRef` is actually a type alias, eg:

```
pub type MyDataRef = Arc<RefCell<MyData>>;
```

I changed to `MyDataRef` to newtype for this example so I could `unsafe impl Send + Sync` on it.

Comment: Ok, well I figured out an (obvious, duh!) solution that works without unsafe.   Just make MyDataRef directly wrap MyDataPrivate with Arc<RwLock<..>>.    [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3dcfbd40781d0f6b60c238fe382f7aba).  That solves my problem.    I'm leaving the question open because I'm still curious if its safe/correct to impl Send + Sync for RefCell in this situation.

Comment: Take this rule of thumb: if this would be sound, you wouldn't need unsafe for this as the impls would already be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, I would not call this sound.

In Rust, it's expected that undefined behavior can only happen within `unsafe` blocks.  This `impl` violates that expectation:

```
impl ChangeName for MyDataRef {
    fn change_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.0.borrow_mut().change_name(name);
    }
}
```

This function must not be called from multiple threads at the same time, but there is no static guarantee that it won't be.  If you want to shift that burden to the caller, this function must be marked `unsafe` and the safety restriction documented.  You can't do this without marking the trait method itself `unsafe` and then *all* implementations would need to be `unsafe` even if they otherwise wouldn't need to be.

I don't think your example code invokes any undefined behavior since you take an exclusive lock before trying to borrow from the `RefCell`, but there really isn't a compelling reason why you need to structure your data this way in the first place.

What you have here is effectively `RwLock<Arc<RefCell<_>>>` and this nesting makes *absolutely no sense.*  You have non-thread-safe interior mutability inside of thread-safe shared ownership inside of thread-safe interior mutability.  It's mixing together stuff with conflicting thread-safe-ness and in an order that isn't useful.  (You can tell that it doesn't make sense precisely *because* you're having to invoke `unsafe` in order to do what you want!  If the data model is causing a huge amount of friction then it's probably not the right model.)

`RwLock<Arc<T>>` *can* be useful when you want the ability to replace an `Arc` with another `Arc`<sup>1</sup>, but is not useful when you want to change the `T` within the `Arc`.

`Arc<RefCell<T>>` makes no sense at all as you're wrapping a non-thread-safe interior mutability type in a thread-safe shared ownership type.

Instead, use:

- `Rc<RefCell<_>>` if you need single-threaded shared ownership with interior mutability, or
- `Arc<Mutex<_>>` or `Arc<RwLock<_>>` if you need multi-threaded shared ownership with interior mutability.

  - `Arc<Mutex<_>>` makes sense when you always or almost always need exclusive access.
  - `Arc<RwLock<_>>` makes sense when you almost always need shared access, but occasionally need exclusive access.  Note in particular that `std::sync::RwLock` is not guaranteed to be "fair" which means that a sufficiently-high amount of read activity can theoretically starve writers indefinitely.

---

<sup>1</sup> As evidence that this can be useful, the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap/latest/arc_swap/) crate implements conceptually the same thing as `RwLock<Arc<T>>` but with better performance.  Sometimes you have a shared data structure that you want the ability to update atomically, but without interrupting other threads that are still using the old value.  This ownership model allows a kind of "snapshotting" where threads/tasks will see either the old data or the new data, but never a mixture of the two.

Comment: nice to know about `arc-swap`, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, `RefCell` is *never* thread-safe (specifically it never implements `Sync`), because it has internal counters for mutable and immutable borrows that are incremented non-atomically. If you were allowed to have two references to the same `RefCell` on different threads, and they both tried to borrow or release a borrow at the same time, they could end up in a data race where the counters are incremented or decremented at the same time, which could corrupt them and lead to e.g. bypassing the runtime checks and allowing conflicting borrows, which is undefined behavior.

For a version of `RefCell` that can be accessed across threads, you need to use `RwLock` instead.